# Magento 245 SoapClient Class Removed From PHP 8.0

Tags: magento2, api, soap, magento-upgrade, php8

Magento241 is working with PHP7.4 and 7.4 have SoapClient and i have custom api call that uses Soapclient.
i just upgrade to magento245 and php 8.0 and Soapclient stop working.

Any one have idea ? any alternate of SoapClient with PHP 8.0  ?

**Note : i do not want to use Rest API call , i must need to use SOAP**

Comment: Have you installed php8.0-soap php extension?
If not here is two commands install it and check.
1. sudo apt update
2. sudo apt-get install php8.0-soap

Answer (score 0):

In **`PHP 8.0`**, the SoapClient class has been removed from the core PHP library. However, it is still available as an extension called **`"soap"`**. You can use this extension to use the SoapClient class in your Magento 2 codebase.

1. First, you need to make sure the soap extension is installed and enabled on your server. You can check if the extension is installed by running the following command: **`php -m | grep soap`**. If the extension is not installed, you can install it using your preferred method (e.g. package manager, PECL, manual compilation).
2. Once the extension is installed, you can use the SoapClient class in your Magento 2 code as you would in previous versions of PHP. Below is small code for if you want testing.
3. Make sure you have enabled soap in your **`php.ini`** file by removing the semicolon before soap in the extensions section.
4. It is also recommended to test your code thoroughly after upgrading to PHP
   8.0 to ensure that everything is working as expected and that there are no compatibility issues.

Here's an example of how you can create a new SoapClient instance and call a method:

```
<?php
    $client = new SoapClient('http://example.com/wsdl');
    $result = $client->someMethod();
    var_dump($result);
?>
```

Let me know if any query

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i already check soap extension and it is already enabled . i m getting this error 'Function ("SoapClient") is not a valid method for this service'

Comment: Yes, your error said soap is not available on your server.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/izm9u8F.png - but if i run php -m it shows soap

Comment: Open frontend phpmyadmin and check soap is enable or not for php 8.0. https://prnt.sc/PK559_EMEF9f

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/50PcgiF.png : yes alrrady show enabled in phpinfo

Comment: Okay so it installed for php8.0 version?

Comment: yes for php8.0 ,i insalled  for php8.0

Comment: First can you try using basic root script.

Comment: thank you for discussion , i found solution and posted as answer

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my issue
i just check magento245 core files and found that fedex module have soap call
and fedex module use below class for api call

**Magento\Framework\Webapi\Soap\ClientFactory**

and i use above class and worked for me